# How to set custom font on ToolbarAndroid in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am learning `react-native` programming where I need to set custom fontFamily on toolbar title. I have added TTF font in assets/fonts folder of my android directory.

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   toolbar: {
     backgroundColor: '#2E8B57',
     height: 40,
     fontFamily: 'roboto_thin'
   },
 });

 <ToolbarAndroid title='Login' titleColor='white'
            onIconClicked={() => this.props.navigator.pop()}
            style={styles.toolbar}/>
```

However `ToolbarAndroid` title font is not setting & getting a warning while running the application.

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `fontFamily` supplied to `ToolbarAndroid`...

Can anyone help me for How to set custom font family on `ToolbarAndroid` title. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is this

```
<ToolbarAndroid>
    <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'yourFont' }}>Title Text</Text>
</ToolbarAndroid>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no documented way to set it (if you spare your time and play with the source codes you may find your way).

Apart from that complication, even though you're developing your application just for Android, you can still use *[react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)*, where you're able to render a custom toolbar, that may contain any React element - Icons, Images, Texts. It supports both platforms and offers a real easy navigation across app [Scenes](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md#scene).